# How to add (coding or through storyboard) Favourite - content of cells (UITableviewcell) and UIView it self

Tags: uiview, uitableview, nsmutablearray, ios5

i'm bit stumped to know how to achieve favourite option i.e. i have a lot of static cells in various views and i want user to select that cell and it adds to favourite, and idea is more like favourite contacts when user wants to view favourite cells (content) it will go to a view which will load all favourite marked cells / views.

any idea or leads on how to achieve this?

i only want to favourite (star) either cells  and uiview and show up on new view to show selected favs, i'm not using core data and only using NSMutablearray mostly.

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the following by following code - for others who are interested.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

Step 1: In your data model (maybe core data, or arrays, or dictionaries, you did not specify), include a `BOOL` property like `isFavorite`.

Step 2: You can then adjust the display of the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` when you configure the cell by checking this property. For example, you could have a `UIImageView` as a subview with a pretty star with the `hidden` property set appropriately.

Comment: my cell content is static cells and are prepopulated (i'm fairly new to ios so i populated the data through storyboard) notsure if this will work there?

Comment: do you have any reference code i can look at, i'm bit confused at property of isFavourite